# check if the output of "cat" is not empty

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Is it possible to know if the output of the following command is not empty?

```
cat anyfile.txt | grep anymessage
```

without put the displayed output into a variable and without redirect the displayed output to a file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The grep command exits with status 1 if no match was found. You can use the exit status like this:

```
whatever | grep pattern
echo $?
```

In a shell script you may even write:

```
if whatever | grep pattern ; then
     # match was found
else
     # not found
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do `grep 'sometext' anyfile.txt >/dev/null` then nothing will be printed.

However, if you read `$?` after, it will show 0 if it matched lines and 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell grep `-q` to be quiet:

```
if  grep -q anymessage anyfile.txt ; then
    # found
else
    # not found
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small script with an if statement and print out true or false.

Answer (score 0):

also "grep -c anymessage anyfile.txt" can be used (-c gets the count of matches)